# Translate physical address to process/virtual address?

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management

I've noticed that one of the cores goes into an infinite loop, leading another core to complain about it and freeze. I have the physical memory address at which it goes into a loop (and is constant everytime). How can I find out which program/kernel module is mapped to that area in memory?

Comment: CPU cores operate on virtual addresses. How do you know the physical address?

Comment: I have never really done this, but [this information](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt) ought to be sufficient to find out. Search for PFN in question in all `/proc/<pid>/pagemap' files. But how do you know the physical address, do you have some kind of in-circuit debugger?

Comment: This sounds extremely superficial and overblown, but I'll gladly see an answer.

Comment: @NikolaiNFetissov I have Intel's ITP that I use to pause execution. I need to double check their documentation to see if the address provided are virtual or not.

Comment: Intel ITP can show both physical and virtual address.